# Selenium, Getting Text from a tag nested within a div class

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm stuck on this problem for quite a while.

So I'm using Selenium for web scraping, and am stuck in extracting texts from the html. I tried to look at other answers around this topic but they do not work.

This is the snippet of my code:

```
# Extract listing links
product_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='professional-box') # find all div element 
product_link = []
for product_element in product_elements: #for loop iterating a list of elements
    content = product_element.find('div', class_='text-box type-a') 
    if content:
        link = content.find('a').get('href')    #get link
        product_link.append({'link':link}) #append "link" dict with value from link variable in product_link list

#Visit all listing links and scrape the data
product_info = []
for product in product_link: #for loop iterating a list of one dict [{"link"}]
    driver.get(product['link']) # get from the dict [{"link"}]
    button = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "text-box left-pad-25") #click all the detail buttons
    for btn in button:
        btn.click()
    if product:
        name_parent = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'text-box') #get name 
        name = name_parent.find('a').text

        facebook_parent = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'left-facebook phone-number').get('href')   
        facebook = facebook_parent.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'a').get('href')
```

The problematic part is after `if product:`,
particularly on `name_parent.find`. I also tried `facebook_parent.find_element` and

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='text-box']/p").getText()
```

but all did not work

I want to extract text from this source code:

```
<div class="text-box">
<p>Lingga Studio</p>
</div>
```

The traceback for the name_parent.find is:

```
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Code\Archify.py", line 51, in <module>
    name = name_parent.find('a').text
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find'
```

The traceback for the facebook_parent.find_element is:

```
return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
```

The traceback for the  `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='text-box']/p").getText()` is:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `<p>` tag inside div class "text-box" have an anchor `<a>` tag.

Try directly with `name_parent.text`

Second, the `facebook_parrent` is already a `WebElement`. So you don't need to use `find_element` again, you can directly use `get_attribute('href')`.

Comment: Hello, this solution worked partially. It managed to extract the text for "name". However, it couldn't extract other datas.

I noticed that the source code is a bit different between "name" and other elements. For example:

<p class="left-instagram phone-number">
<a target="_blank" href="https://instagram.com/lingga_studio" rel="nofollow">lingga_studio</a>
</p>